# how to decide which protocol should i use for a WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf, protocols

I've almost finished a server-client(Sockets) application that :

Send/Receive Files (large sizes)

Send/Receive Commands (chat, file explorer, task manager, restart/turnoff, lock mouse/keyboard..etc)
then after i read about WCF it looks much better for `Commands` to use instead of Sockets.

so now I'm starting step by step to use WCF but im confused about which protocol would be the best for my application. there's too many of them in [.Net 4.0] 

which one do you suggest me to choose and why!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help you....

[Choosing a Transport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733769.aspx)